# python decorator, decorate a recursive function to run it many times

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a recursive function (f calls itself):

```
def f(x) : 
    ....
```

I want to run this function multiple times. I use the following decorator:

```
def iter_f(func) : 
    def newf(x):
        for i in range(10):  
            func(x)
    return newf
@iter_f
def f(x): a RECURSIVE function.
```

When i call f(x), I am calling a function that iterate itself infinite times.I am curious what is the solution still using decorator, without wrap f inside a new function g, and decorate g.

Thanks.

---

Thanks for point out that the problem was due to f is recursive.

---

[Decorating recursive functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757871/decorating-recursive-functions-in-python) this post has a similar problem, maybe this is not a good place to use decorator?

Comment: Please clarify -- when you call `f(x)`, your function gets called an infinite number of times? I don't get this behavior when I run your code. `f(x)` gets called only 10 times for me.

Comment: yes, you're right, sorry for the confusion, I will delete the problem.

Comment: The problem was caused because f is a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
def iter_f(func):
    def newf(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(10):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newf

@iter_f
def f(x):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def iter_f(func) : 
    def newf(x):
        for i in range(10):  
            func(x)
    newf._original = func
    return newf


@iter_f
def f(x):
    ...
    call f._original(y)
    ...
```